# Get the last command executed on a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, logging

I'm updating the logging function I use for all my scripts and making it compatible with the [SCCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_System_Center_Configuration_Manager) logging viewer.

Under the fields that the SCCM viewer takes is the component field, and I'll like to fill it with the main command that it's run and I'm logging. For example, if I'm logging "Data copied" and I did that with [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Copy-Item), I'd like that the logs says Copy-Item for that line of the log.

So far I've tested the following methods, using `$$` and the history cmdlets ([Get-History](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Get-History), Add-, etc.), but they only work with the PowerShell console, not with script execution.

The final result I'd like to get is:

[image]

Comment: The only way I can think this would work is if you manually log everything yourself.  Once you get to a pipeline of commands, however, it's just going to fall apart.  For example, if I'm running `Get-ChildItem ... | Where-Object ... | Group-Object ...`, what exactly should the log show? I feel like you'd be further along to just include the line number of the script with `$MyInvocation.ScriptLineNumber`.

Comment: Yes that's what I currently have, on the component field. And maybe you are right it would be pointless. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I wouldn't call it pointless, just very difficult for probably not much gain! I don't think it will be common to have the log file and not have access to the script. I think it will be important to always include the version number of the script in your log, however, so you can be sure that you're looking at the script file that was actually used.

Comment: What about (Get-Content $MyInvocation.ScriptName)[$MyInvocation.ScriptLineNumber - 1]

Comment: I think it is overkill as well btw :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're talking about?

$Folder = "some path"

***$Cmdline = 'Remove-Item $Folder -Force -Recurse'

Invoke-Expression $Cmdline

Write-Host $Cmdline.replace("`$Folder",$Folder)***